# Multiple stores or websites magento

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, products, category-products, multi-website

I set up a multi store (under the same website) in my Magento instalation. However, even having different root categories set up for each store, I get all of the products (from both root categories) when I search for a product in any of the stores.

In fact, I need to have different products on each store. They cannot share products. Is it possible to do it only with different stores? Or do I need to create different websites? if I need to create different websites, how can I do that?

What I need is:

example.com  -> store 1 with products x
example.com/secondstore -> store 2 with products y

Please, help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although, as per http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/stores-multiple.html and https://www.mavenecommerce.com/blog/magento-store-view-vs-website-vs-magento-multi-store/, you can achieve your goal of different products set and categories by multi-stores. But I think you have made some minor mistake while creating the multi-store setup.

Please check, whether you have followed complete process of creating multi-stores or not.

To crosscheck, please verify that you have:

- made changes in base URL of each store.
- created a new folder for the second store and copied index.php and .htaccess from the root directory.